# Symbol visibility of indirectly linked libraries

Tags: c++, linux

say I have an application that dynamically links to firstlib.so while firstlib.so links to secondlib.so, will my application also see the symbols/functions of secondlib.so? If yes, how can I prevent that ( I want to avoid people mixing up symbols and functions)?

Comment: Will the use of namespaces help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your application will see symbols from `secondlib.so`.

Every symbol from every library is put in the global symbol table of the process unless you requested otherwise.

You might want to use `dlopen` with `RTLD_LOCAL` to prevent that but take into account it might have some effects on the code.

One such effect I encountered in the past is that `dynamic_cast` might not work under specific circumstances.